# Propel3 Generator Location, propel-gen

Tags: propel

http://files.propelorm.org doesn't resolve for me so I downloaded Propel3 from Github https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3. I can't get it to run the way my previous 1.7 worked though. Was the `propel-gen` renamed, or was it removed?

Perhaps the Github I used was incorrect and the Propel file location has changed to another URL?

Comment: Propel commands aren't the same between v1.x and v2 and according to the above link you should be using v2.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Which link above? Is there a v2 somewhere, I only see 3 on Github.

Comment: The link above points to v3, and it's mentioned there that the documentation used is that of v2.  See the installation section https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3#installation.
So it means that you should use the same commands for v2 in v3, and in this case `propel` and not `propel-gen`

Answer (score 0):

Only Propel v1.x is `propel-gen`, from v2 onwards the command is `propel`